# How can I find all the commented lines in the entire solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If I search them with ctrl+f, they mix up with the  comments, that has 3 bars.
I'll appreciate your help

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Search for this in Visual Studio with regular expression turned on:

```
(^|[^/])//[^/]
```

Comment: It also helps to add `.*;` to this pattern to include only lines having a semicolon. This exludes most "regular" comments.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Not all (commented) lines have to end with a semicolon so one should use this with caution.

Answer (score 1):

You can search based on a [regular expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) or [wildcard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afy96z92%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), instead of "//" exactly. For regex searches you'd use "^:b*//[^/].*$" without the quotes.

Comment: Suggest since _most_ lines end in a semicolon in C# you'd include that somewhere in your pattern to avoid finding actual code comments - which probably wouldn't include many semicolons.

Answer (score 0):

In the visual studio. Select View->Task list. There would be a drop down at the top of the talk list window where you can select Comments. This would show all the comments in the solution.

Comment: Actually that shows all the comments that have pre-declared tokens in them such as TODO and HACK.

Comment: TODO is listed under user task. But if you select the drop down to pick comments, you'll find the comments getting listed.

Comment: Mine doesn't behave that way :) Comments shows the comment line of anything with a token in it. Default VS2010 set up, not sure what to say!