# Locating all comments within a code file using the Visual Studio 2017 SDK

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-sdk

Specifically, I want to obtain a list/collection of all the code comment lines for use in a small extension to intellisense to handle certain varieties of markup done through comments in C# and C++.

I strongly suspect Visual Studio already maintains such a list without me needing to explicitly query a language parser for the information directly, but if it exists, I have no idea where to look for it.

Comment: This post may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6284508/1489570

Comment: Does intellisense support third-party extensions?

Comment: @VTT unless Microsoft is lying or I am grotesquely misreading, yes, the functionality associated with intellisense is extendable: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/inside-the-editor#intellisense